# Не работает проверка if(isset($_PHP[ "form_ex" ]))

Tags: php, form

В файле несколько форм для запросов, надо сделать проверки форм, если этого не сделать, все формы с запросами выполнятся, как по мне это не правильно. Вот с помощью `if (isset($_POST['update']))` делаю проверку, но не выходит.
В чем проблема?

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="telephone[]"> 
   <input type="text" name="telephone[]">       
   <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="form_ex">
   <button type="submit" name="update" id="btn_post_phones" value="button_value">Update phone</button>
</form>
```

---

```
if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {  
      var_dump ('true -->');
      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump(json_decode($_POST["phones"], true));
} else {
      var_dump ('false-->');
      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump(json_decode($_POST["phones"], true));
}

//string(8) "false-->"
//array(2) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(6) "345345"
//  [1]=>
//  string(6) "345345"
//}
```

---

```
    $('#form').submit(function(event) {
    var arrPhones = new Array();  
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="telephone[]"]').each(
            function() {
                arrPhones.push($(this).val()); 
            });
        var data='phones='+JSON.stringify(arrPhones);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'regist.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  data,
            // data:  $('input[name="telephone[]"]').serialize,
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log('before ' + data);
            },
            success: function(response){ 
              console.log(response);
            }       
        });
    });
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` и смотрите какие данные приходят

Comment: 1) у вас два инпута с одинаковым именем. 2) в $_POST придут параметры с именами элементов формы, а не самой формы

Comment: `input`-ы мне нужны с такими именами, в `var_dump($_POST)` приходит массив который мне нужен. @rjhdby

Comment: Может проблемы из-за AJAX? @rjhdby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В массив `$_POST` не передается название формы. Укажите атрибуты формы `method` и `action`. По логике, не должно быть два элемента формы с одинаковыми названиями (`name="json"`). Если Вам нужно передать несколько значений с одинаковым именем, используйте запись `name="json[]"` - тогда на сервере значение будут собраны в массив в переменной `$_POST['json']`.

В Вашем случае, что бы понять данные какой из форм были отправлены, можно передать скрытое значение через `input type="hidden"`.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="regist.php">
   <input type="text" name="telephone[]"> 
   <input type="text" name="telephone[]">       
   <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="form_ex">
   <button type="submit" name="update" id="btn_post_phones" value="button_value">Update phone</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

Проверяем значение скрытого `input`

```
if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {      
  // $_POST['form'] = form_ex
} else {
  echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

**JS**

Событие `submit()`([документация](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)) нужно вешать на форму, а не на кнопку (к тому же id кнопки Вы написали не правильно). Вы собирали данные из `input[name="telephone"]` в массив, хотя таких элементов на форме нет. Тип запроса и путь к скрипту можно брать сразу из формы. Данные из форм можно передавать через `serialize()`([документация](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)).

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        url:  $(this).attr("action"),
        dataType: 'json',  
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log('send');
        },
        success: function(response){ 
          console.log(response);
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: Я промахнулся, у меня две формы и я забыл поменять `btn` и `name`. И мне нужен формат `JSON`, а так я более менее понял о чем вы.  @RaZik

Comment: Поменяйте dataType: 'html' на dataType: 'json'' (скрипт должен возвращать валидный json). Обновил ответ

Comment: еще вопросик, если я хочу взять только `input="telephone[]"`, а у меня еще есть `input="name"` или другие @RaZik

Comment: Если нужно передать не все данные из формы, тогда нужно перечислять нужные в data Ajax

Comment: а как правильно передать? я передаю данные, в консоли выводит то что я хочу передать и в `regist` тоже, но оно попадает в `false` @RaZik

Comment: Правильно поставьте вопрос. Что именно,как передаете и что нужно получить в итоге

Comment: `$('input[name="telephone[]]"').serialize()` выводит `string(8) "false-->" string(2) "[]"` в файле (не в консоли). (`string(8) "false-->"` я написал для проверки). Если написать `data:  {data}` тои выводит `string(8) "false-->"` `и массив`.  @RaZik

Comment: Не правильно расставили кавычки! `$('input[name="telephone[]"]').serialize()` работает

Comment: `string(8) "false-->" string(27) "{"telephone":["123","456"]}"` может я скину опять код?  `form`, `php`, `ajax` (заменю) на новый. @RaZik

Comment: выводит `string(8) "false-->" string(27) "{"telephone":["123","456"]}"` где?

Comment: в файле `regist` @RaZik

Comment: Так выложите код файла regist.php

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75897/discussion-between---and-razik).

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form" name="form_ex" method="POST">
   <input  type="text" name="json"> 
   <input  type="text" name="json">       
   <button type="submit" name="update" id="btn_post_phones1">Update phone</button>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['form_ex'])) {      
  /***/
} else {
  var_dunp('sory');
}
```

Вы метод не указали.

Comment: Я добавил `POST`, но все ровно в `var_dump($_POST)` приходит массив который мне нужен. @Андрей Александру

Comment: Может проблемы с `AJAX`?

Comment: @МишаПодлевских Не стоит без согласования пытаться редактировать чужой ответ, внося правку, которая не задумана автором ответа.

Comment: Я случайно, я думал что свой правлю, хотел кусок кода добавить